# fragment shader doesn't show color when using texture

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

What I try to do is to display an object in openGL which is a textured kinect mesh. As I need to be able to select a volume within the kinect mesh, I've created a box. In order to see what happens when changing the box, I also want to display the box with a white color.

In order to do this, I use 2 vertex and fragment shaders. For the kinect mesh I have a vertex and fragment shader that output color based on the texture.

```
#version 430

layout(location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 VertexColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 TextureCoord;

out vec3 Color;
out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model, view, proj;

void main()
{
    // Texture coodinates to fragment shader
    TexCoord = TextureCoord;

    // Color to fragment shader
    Color = VertexColor;

    // Position to fragment shader
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);
}
```

'

```
#version 430

in vec3 Color;
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 FragColor;

layout (binding=0) uniform sampler2D Tex1;

void main() 
{
    //FragColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);
    FragColor = texture2D( Tex1, TexCoord );
}
```

And for the box I have a vertex and fragment shader where the output color is vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0).

```
#version 430

layout(location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;

uniform mat4 model, view, proj;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);
}
```

'

```
#version 430

out vec4 FragColor;

void main() 
{
    FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}
```

If I use the fragment shader of the kinect mesh as shown, I only see the kinect mesh, but don't see the box.

When I use `FragColor=vec4(Color,1.0);` and thus not the texture color, I do see the box.

In my code I switch between the shader programs using glUseProgram(), but this is not doing the trick. Can anybody help me, or explain which additional info is needed to help?

Comment: Try to use `texture` instead of `texture2D`

Comment: I had that initially, gives same result.

Comment: Hmm oké, could you try to post the code where you bind the relevant texture before rendering the kinect mesh? (also, you could try to visualize the texture coords by `FragColor = vec4(TexCoord, 0.0f, 1.0f)` to see if they're not black (if color is always black, it means your texture coordinates weren't properly set)

Comment: It's better to have your codes about `Tex1` in texture slot 0, how you upload the texture data, how you set the texture sample parameter, etc [as @JoeyDewd said]. on the other hand, maybe you can try to adjust your Tex1's texture parameter like these below: `glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GL_LINEAR );` and `glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER , GL_LINEAR );`, since sometime, filter set wrong or keep default may cause similar issue.